# How to use an abstract class rvalue reference member?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I have an abstract class `Base` and derived class `Derived`:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int n) :_n(n) { _arr = new int[n]; }
    virtual ~Base() { delete[] _arr; }
    Base(Base&& other) { _n = other._n; _arr = other._arr; other._arr = nullptr; other._n = 0; }
    virtual void func() = 0;

private:
    int _n;
    int* _arr;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int m, int n) : Base(n), _m(m) { _arr = new int[m]; }
    ~Derived() { delete[] _arr; }
    Derived(Derived&& other) : Base(std::move(other)) { _m = other._m; _arr = other._arr; other._arr = nullptr; other._m = 0; }
    void func() override { cout << "func"; }
private:
    int _m;
    int* _arr;
};
```

Then I have a class `Bag` which contains a rvalue reference of `Base`:

```
class Bag
{
public:
    Bag(Base&& b) : _b(std::move(b)) {}
    void func() { _b.func(); }
private:
    Base&& _b;
};

int main()
{
    Bag bag(Derived(1, 1));
    bag.func();
}
```

I use a rvalue reference member `_b` because I just want to take a temporary object in `Bag`'s constructor. However, after `bag.func()` I got an error: abort() is called. It seems that `bag._b`'s type changes from `Derived` to `Base` after the temporary object `Derived(1,1)` is destructed.

`bag.func()` works after I delete `virtual ~Base() { delete[] _arr; }`. Why? If I need `Base`'s destructor, how can I change my code?

Comment: Why do both `Base` and `Derived` have their own arrays? Why do you use pointers, `new[]` and  `delete[]` instead of a simple `std::vector` (which means you could follow the rule of zero instead of the rule of three/five which you don't follow now)?

Comment: `Bag(Base&& b) : _b(std::move(b)) {}` creates a dangling reference to `Derived(1, 1)`.  Life-time extension is not transitive.  At the end of the full expression `Bag bag(Derived(1, 1));` the temporary is destroyed.

Comment: After the temporary object is destroyed, any attempts to use it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `_arr` is not necessary. I use `_arr` just for destructor's necessity.

Comment: Dangling reference.  Use after delete.  "`bag.func()` works..." is a bold claim.

Comment: why do yuo want a `Base&&` member in `Bag` ? Whats the actualy aim? There might be a different solution

Comment: This seems to be very much an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need a `Base&&` member? What actual problem is that rvalue reference supposed to solve?

Comment: The copy constructor of `Base` is deleted in my scenario.  My aim is to store a temporary `Base` object in `Bag`'s member.

Comment: @Ryime never going to work.  You get 1 life-time extension, to the constructor's parameter, which is not needed as the lifetime of the parameter and `Derived(1, 1)` is the same.  Life-time extension can not be passed on, so when the full expression ends `Derived(1, 1)` is destroyed.

Comment: Storing a *temporary* object is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Base&& _b` is a reference to the temporary object, when that temporary is destroyed at the end of the line `Bag bag(Derived(1, 1));` the reference becomes a dangling reference and any use of the reference is undefined behaviour.

You could change `_b` to a value instead but that would [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) your object.

If you want to store a polymorphic object the only real option is to use a pointer (ideally a smart one). For example:

```
class Bag
{
public:
    Bag(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& b) : _b(std::move(b)) {}
    void func() { _b->func(); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> _b;
};

int main()
{
    Bag bag(std::make_unique<Derived>(1, 1));
    bag.func();
}
```

Note that you should also ensure that `Base` and `Derived` follow the [rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) otherwise you may encounter issues when you assign objects.

Comment: it would be possible to keep OPs `main` as is, and construct the unique_ptr from a copy, right?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number • It'd require making something like a *virtual clone* member function.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: If you do a copy anyways, why store a pointer then ?

Comment: @nick for polymorphism. `Base` is abstract

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number to keep the `main` as is you'd have to make the `Bag` constructor a template, even if you do that there's a risk that you accidentally pass in a `Base` reference to a `Derived` object and the copy would slice

Comment: @AlanBirtles Is it safe if the copy constructor of `Base` is deleted?

Comment: @Ryime for the rule of five you need to delete/implement the copy constructor and both assignment operators